# php and the use statement in child classes

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

I'm working with laravel - though the problem surely isn't confined to just laravel - and in my base controller I want to import some common-used classes, so I am `use`ing them in the base class. However when I come to use them in the child class, I have to `use` them again otherwise the class isn't found - is this correct, and if not what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how PHP works. The namespace declaration and use statements are just for that file.

Comment: ah I see, thanks. Searching was difficult thanks to the 'use' keyword.